# Any way to make a batch call on Klout Api

Tags: klout

I am wondering if there is a way to make one call to get the Klout ID for several usernames, or do I have to make one call per username?

Like: http://api.klout.com/v2/identity.json/twitter?screenNames=SteveMartinToGo,SteveMartinOther

Also I am wondering the same about getting the user score.

So is there a way to turn multiple http://api.klout.com/v2/user.json/45598950992084523/score into one call?